# Git repo not found when using git command, but able to open it in a web browser

Tags: git, apache, dns, subdomain

I am new to apache servers, but I was able to get one setup and using a git backend on Windows Server 2012. However, I decided to switch to Ubuntu Server instead, because I thought it would be easier to manage the server with that. On the Windows apache server I had a /git/ directory that contained a test repo and I was able to clone, pull, push, etc. to it. Whenever I opened it in a browser I had it just forward to an error 404, because otherwise it would be an error 403, since its a valid file on the server, which I feel is a security vulnerability. It did not let me log in through a browser strangely enough, unlike my Ubuntu setup. I had no problem doing git clone http://example.com/git/Test.git.

Now that I have moved over to Ubuntu Server. I started using a git subdomain instead of a /git/ dir. I also started using .htaccess files instead of a hardcoded Directory entry for every repo in the apache2.conf. I think that will allow for adding new repositories during runtime through a web page. I thought I had gotten everything working perfectly. When testing the accessibility of my test git repo, it asked for a username and password in the browser, unlike before. The groups and users all logged in fine and correctly handle whether I should get access to the file.

I think I am done with all that, but when I actually go to test cloning the test repo, it asks my username and password, as it should. Then instead of cloning the repo it gives me a fatal: repository 'http://git.example.com/Test.git/' not found. I did check to see if I can locally clone the repo on the server itself, it did not work using the URL, but using the file path worked fine.

I have absolutely no clue why I can access the repo in a browser but not with a git command. Any help would greatly be appreciated.

FYI: obviously I the website I have is not example.com, I am using that to hide my real website URL. The website's DNS settings are all working. You can connect to the regular domain and git subdomain index.html's fine.

**apache2.conf:**

```
DefaultRuntimeDir ${APACHE_RUN_DIR}
PidFile ${APACHE_PID_FILE}

Timeout 300
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 5

User ${APACHE_RUN_USER}
Group ${APACHE_RUN_GROUP}

HostnameLookups Off

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

LogLevel warn

IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.load
IncludeOptional mods-enabled/*.conf

Include ports.conf

<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/example.com/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

AccessFileName .htaccess

<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>

LogFormat "%v:%p %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" vhost_combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %O" common
LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

# Include of directories ignores editors' and dpkg's backup files,
# see README.Debian for details.

# Include generic snippets of statements
IncludeOptional conf-enabled/*.conf

# Include the virtual host configurations:
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

**git.example.com.conf:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName git.example.com

    ServerAdmin admin@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/git/example.com

    SetEnv GIT_PROJECT_ROOT <strong>/var/git/example.com/</strong>
    SetEnv GIT_HTTP_EXPORT_ALL
    ScriptAlias /git/ /usr/lib/git-core/git-http-backend/

    Alias /git/ /var/git/example.com/

    <Directory /usr/lib/git-core>
        Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    <Directory /var/git/example.com/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride AuthConfig
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    LogLevel warn
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

**/var/git/example.com/Test.git/.htaccess:**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Git Verification"
AuthUserFile "/etc/apache2/git.example.com.htpasswd"
AuthGroupFile "/etc/apache2/git.example.com.htgroup"
<RequireAny>
    Require group admin
    <RequireAll>
        Require group user
        Require user my_name
    </RequireAll>
</RequireAny>
```

[image: Image of browser sign-in window working]

[image: Image of browser access to repo working]

Comment: I'm no apache configuration expert, but your setup is definitely wrong: if you log in and see the raw files from a Git repo you're not giving Git the right stuff. You generally want a module that will let Git users run `git upload-pack` and `git receive-pack` (possibly as `git-upload-pack` and `git-receive-pack` depending on setup details), but not let them run arbitrary Git commands. There are instructions [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Smart-HTTP).

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what was wrong, but I think the DNS configuration for the subdomain was done incorrectly and apache was automatically forwarding any subdomain connections the the main website. It is working now and I can still view the git repo in the browser like in the picture above. Although I think git's recommended config settings causes the files to not be viewable in the browser. I am not using their config settings. Thanks for the documentation link, somehow I missed that when trying to fix the server. It was still very useful.

Comment: To begin with remove `<strong>` and `</strong>` from `<strong>/var/git/example.com/</strong>` as those are misplaced html element tags. If you check your log -- you will see the complaint.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I had my DNS settings misconfigured for the subdomain.
This link helped: https://youtu.be/fWD_ciSWklQ

Also I completely started an apache server from scratch to see if that would help. I ran into a weird problem with the starting a site using a2ensite. It would enable the site but I forgot to use sudo so it complained and did not make the marker file in /etc/apache2/sites-available/. I reran the command w/ sudo but it did not create the marker file bc it still thought it was enabled but it really wasent w/o the marker. I did not realize this and the site was forwarding to the main website instead of the domain. You have to disable the website and re-enable it if it says a marker file was not created, you CANNOT just run enable again w/ sudo.

Hope this helps someone.